# Delete grouped blank cells when stacked

Tags: excel, blank-line, vba

I'm trying to sort out a manifest that needs to be converted to a different format. 
Just wondering, is there a way for to find a group of blank cells and delete them, using VBA?

The files look like this:

```
name
address
address
region
-blank line-
-blank line-
-blank line-
Name
Address
Address
Region
-blank line etc
```

What I would like is something to delete out the grouped blank cells. The issue I have is sometimes one of the address columns is blank, (one blank line) so I can't just use `Go to > Special...`

What I would love is if I could work out how to have a VBA to run down the column, pick up a group of 3 or more blank cells on top of each other, and delete those entire rows. 
Is that possible?

Cheers, Nigel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do something like this:

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = TotalRows To 2 Step -1
        'Check if there is more than one blank cell
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = "" Then

            'Count the number of cells that are blank
            Do While Cells(i - j, 1).Value = ""
            If i - j <= 1 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop

            'Delete group of blank of cells
            If i - j <= 1 Then
                Rows(i & ":" & i - j).Delete
            Else
                Rows(i & ":" & i - j + 1).Delete
            End If

            j = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Doesent seem to work. Can i get the above to run on Column D only?

Comment: It works for column A and deletes entire rows. You can easily change it though. Just modify the 1 in cells to the correct column number, change the totalrows to check column D instead of A and you can change rows.delete to cells.delete